# Should be a simple proof in propositional logic using Lemmon's book

Tags: propositional-calculus

In Lemmon's Beginning Logic, page 41 exercise 1g says
to prove that from $\neg (P \cap Q)$ then $\neg P \cup \neg Q$ follows.

1    (1) $\neg (P \cap Q)$  (A)

2    (2) $\neg (\neg P \cup \neg Q)$  (A)

3    (3) $\neg P$  (A)

3    (4) $\neg P \cup \neg Q$  (3 vI)

2,3  (5) $(\neg P \cup \neg Q) \cap \neg(\neg P \cup \neg Q)$  (2,4 &I)

3    (6) $\neg \neg (\neg P \cup \neg Q)$  (2,5 RAA)

3    (7) $\neg P \cup \neg Q$  (6 DN)

This is my first attempt, but line 7 needs to rely on line
1 which hasn't been used in the proof.  Any hints?

Comment: Little wonder that line 7 doesn;t depend on line 1, since it immediately follows from the assumption made on line 3, which is never being discharged. So effectively, all you have shown is that $\neg P$ implies $\neg P \lor \neg Q$

Comment: After the contradiction in step (5) you have to derive $P$ by DN (discharging Assupmtion 3); then you have to assume $\lnot Q$ and repeat, deriving $Q$ by DN again. Now you have $P$ and $Q$ and thus $P \land Q$, that contradicts (1) and now you can use DN again to discharge (2).